# Criteria for inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

I am working with an inequality and I need to prove something of the shape $$c\cdot a+d\cdot b \leq a\cdot b$$
The numbers $a$ and $b$ have a specific form, but for the $c$ and $d$ I only know that $c<b$ and $d<a$. I also know that in some cases that $c>b/2$ or $d>a/2$, so I wanted to know if there is any criteria or a relation between the $c,d$ and the $a,b$ that will give that inequality.

Given that, I could try to prove that my numbers satisfy that relation.

Comment: Assuming the numbers are positive (are they?) all you can derive from $c \lt b, d \lt a$ is $c \cdot a + d \cdot b \lt 2 a b$ which is weaker than the $\le a b$ you need. So there must be something else that's relevant, but missing from your post.

Comment: $ca+db\le ab\iff (a-d)(b-c)\ge cd$. If $b>c>b/2$ and $a>d>a/2$, then $0<b-c<c$ and $0<a-d<d$, so $(a-d)(b-c)<cd$, so, in fact, the exact opposite is true.

Comment: @dxiv Yes, they are positive. Maybe the question was wrongly posed. What I am asking is if it is a criteria for $c$ and $d$ when that inequality holds. I know that with my information thats the only thing to conclude, so I am asking for some relations that my numbers should satisfy, so the inequality is true.

Comment: @user236182 of course they are not both $c>b/2$ and $d>a/2$. I put that to say that I need a relation more complex than $c\leq b/2$ and $d\leq a/2$.

Comment: @jiyanez There is no magic relation, unless you provide more details on that `specific form` that $a, b$ supposedly have, and on the relations to/between $c, d$. With what you posted so far, the question essentially amounts to "how can I prove that $x + y < 42$ for my secret $x, y$".